# Rails 4 - Toaster notifications rather than flash notifications

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, notifications, ruby-on-rails-4, toastr

I am using this library, (https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) and I am trying to push my Flash notifications to the javascript function Toastr has provided for me. How do I call this function for every error or notification?

This is one of the methods that are used for making a toaster notification:

```
toastr.warning('This is a warning!')
```

I tried making a method in the ApplicationController to see if I could call that method on default errors from CanCan. I have various versions of the method, none of which worked.

```
def toast(type, text)
    #if Logic here for various errors/notifications
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render action: "toastr.warning(#{text})", layout: false}
    end
end

def toast(type, text)
    #if Logic here for various errors/notifications
    "toastr.warning(#{text})"
end
```

And then I try to use this method in the CanCan block:

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    toast :error, exception.message
    redirect_to root_url
end
```

I would assume that this is possible, but I am just unsure how to implement it. Not many try to do this, and there is probably a reason. I am open to any suggestions on how to do what I am trying to do.

Here is a testing application that implements the Toast notifications:
http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I'd recommend is to make a new `flash` type for this sort of thing and then render that as JS in your layout.

```
ApplicationController

def toast(type, text)
  flash[:toastr] = { type => text }
end


app/views/layouts/<your layout>.html.erb
# (or in a partial to be reused in various layouts)
# the <script> tag isn't needed if code snippet is
# included in an existing script block, of course.

<% if flash[:toastr] %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    <% flash[:toastr].each do |type, message| %>
      toastr.<%= type %>(<%= message.inspect %>)
    <% end %>
  </script>
<% end %>
```

So this way you get all the standard behavior you're used to from the `flash` object and you get easy to understand javascript written in your views directly via erb. You may need to add an options hash to the `ApplicationController#toast` method so you can do a `flash.now[:toastr]` at times, of course. And so on... But this should get you started.

Comment: With a little bit of tweaking such as adding `Raw` on the `message.inspect`. I got it to work. Thanks for the help!